# Android BroadcastReceiver error

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Hello i create one broadcast test but no work

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BeaconsBroadcast"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in my MainActivity:

```
protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try{

            Log.e("ENTRO ","ENTRO");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast");

            startService(i);
        }catch (Exception e){Log.e("ERROR","ERRR");}

    }
```

mi broadcast class:

```
public class BeaconsBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("ENTRO ","EBTROPOOOOO RECIVE");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Se ha pulsado el botón.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

in logcat:

```
12-02 11:12:59.551  28588-28588/com.mydomain.myapplication W/ContextImpl﹕ Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.MainActivity.onStop:101 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop:1235
12-02 11:12:59.552     927-2008/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast } U=0: not found
```

where my error?

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring BeaconsBroadcast as a BroadcastReceiver but are using startService(i) to invoke it which is causing the issue.
You need to use the sendBroadcast(i) function to send a broadcast to a BroadcastReceiver.
Also Since you have set android:exported="false" for BroadcastReceiver use

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Context context).sendBroadcast(Intent)

Comment: Hello i use  this.sendBroadcast(i); no mark a error but no work :/ mi class BeaconsBroacast dont execute :/

Comment: use LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i) because you have defined it as android:exported="false" so it will take only local broadcast.

Comment: i have  @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        try{

            Log.e("ENTRO ","ENTRO");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast");

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);

        }catch (Exception e){Log.e("ERROR","ERRR");}

    }

Comment: <receiver android:name=".BeaconsBroadcast"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.android.kontacktestbeacons.BeaconsBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>    And dont work :/

Comment: why do you send the broadcast in onStop(). It is called when the activity is about to be stopped. Try to send the broadcast in onResume() for testing.

Comment: im try in onResume dont work, log cat no log error, but mi code in broadcast class no execute

Comment: 12-02 12:17:28.002    1624-4490/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114
12-02 12:17:28.071    5122-5122/com.mydomain.myapplication E/ENTRO﹕ ENTRO

Answer (score 0):

Hello im fine by manifest

```
<receiver android:name="BeaconsBroadCast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.tutorialspoint.CUSTOM_INTENT">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

in application tag